# Search page showing all results on first page in Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento, search, filter, pagination

- On product search, All result shows on first page.
- When I click on price filter on layer navigation, it shows results in proper way with pagination.
- Except price, no other filter in layer navigation works.

But product listing on category page is working fine.

Comment: Can you provide us with some more information? For example your  (template) local.xml.

Comment: Some question (as in sentence with a question mark) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

before magento return the result to your page, magento collect all attribute of products you have called by category or result or searching.
after that magento put all attribute into column left(or right depend on developer want to put where, default is column left). when you filter on an attributite of product that mean only products has this attribute showing on your page and magento collect all attribute of the products and put the attributes to the left menu.
 this it not the bug